# How to take only that part of a string which occurs before a pattern of 2 dots?

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching, gsub

I used a code of regular expressions which only took stuff before the 2nd occurrence of a dot. The following is the code:-

```
colnames(final1)[i] <- gsub("^([^.]*.[^.]*)..*$", "\\1", colnames(final)[i])
```

But now i realized i wanted to take the stuff before the first occurrence of a pattern of 2 dots.

I tried

```
 gsub(",.*$", "", colnames(final)[i]) (changed the , to ..)
 gsub("...*$", "", colnames(final)[i])
```

But it didn't work

The example to try on
KC1.Comdty...PX_LAST...USD......Comdty........

converted to

KC1.Comdty.

or

"LIT.US.Equity...PX_LAST...USD......Comdty........"

to

"LIT.US.Equity."

Can anyone suggest anything?
Thanks

Comment: Please use a reproducible example

Comment: just did it! please check now!

Comment: I think you need to escape the dot with \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `sub` to match 2 or more dots followed by other characters and replace it with blank

```
sub("\\.{2,}.*", "", str1)
#[1] "KC1.Comdty"    "LIT.US.Equity"
```

The `.` is a metacharacter implying any character.  So, we need to escape (`\\.`) to get the literal meaning of the character

#### data

```
str1 <- c("KC1.Comdty...PX_LAST...USD......Comdty.......", "LIT.US.Equity...PX_LAST...USD......Comdty........")
```

Comment: perfection : akrun

Comment: Sorry bro... Just did. Tell me one thing, why do you prefer to keep mystery around you :)

Comment: @AbhaySaini  Some people likes to be known and some don't.  I belong to the latter group

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `strsplit`:

```
str1 <- c("KC1.Comdty...PX_LAST...USD......Comdty.......", "LIT.US.Equity...PX_LAST...USD......Comdty........")

sapply(strsplit(str1, "\\.{2}\\w"), "[", 1)
# [1] "KC1.Comdty."    "LIT.US.Equity."
```

To also include the dot at the end with @akrun's answer, one can do:

```
sub("\\.{2}\\w.*", "", str1)
# [1] "KC1.Comdty."    "LIT.US.Equity."
```

Comment: gsub was more efficient i think bro

Comment: @AbhaySaini I never my answer is more efficient. But it is another option. Not sure why you unaccepted akrun's answer though if you think his answer is more efficient. Is it because I was able to also leave the dot at the end?

Comment: sorry bro...never meant to unaccept it...accepted it

Comment: the problem is i can only accept one answer...and since gsub was one was written first...i have to accept that and hence this one gets automatically unaccepted

Comment: @AbhaySaini That is indeed how StackOverflow works. You can only accept one answer as the best one, but you can upvote more than one answer if you think they are also helpful